# Show that a matrix is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{M}_n (\mathbb{C})$. If $A^2B + BA^2 = 2ABA$ then exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $(AB-BA)^k = 0$.

I tried solve with minimal polynomial, but I did not have much effect.

Comment: The hypothesis is that $[A,[A,B]]=0$, and the conclusion that $[A,B]$ is nilpotent. This is a clearer way to state this, IMO. This result is known as *Jacobson's lemma*; googling should find proofs —for example, [this one](http://jankobracic.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/on-the-jacobsons-lemma.pdf)

Comment: This is hardly an exercise... It always helps to explain in what context your question occured, @jonjones.

Comment: Wow, that seems a lot more difficult than I initially thought.

Comment: I'm preparing for my test. I already spent two days in this question.

Comment: Well, as I said, this is a very cruel exercise in linear algebra, if that is how you encountered it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$AB-BA$ is a nilpotent matrix if it commutes with $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299640/ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent-matrix-if-it-commutes-with-a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's denote by $C$ the matrix $AB-BA$.
 From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191879/nilpotent-matrices-over-field-of-characteristic-zero) is enough to show that $\operatorname{Tr}(C^n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
 From Mariano's comment we easily see that $AC=CA\Rightarrow AC^2=CAC=C^2A\Rightarrow\ldots \Rightarrow AC^m=C^mA, \ \forall m\in\mathbb N$. Therefore
$$
C^n=C^{n-1}C=C^{n-1}(AB-BA)=\\
AC^{n-1}B-C^{n-1}BA=A(C^{n-1}B)-(C^{n-1}B)A.
$$
We [conclude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product) that $\operatorname{Tr}(C^n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Nice one (+1): But I did not know that there was this same problem posted in the past. There are some other insights too. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299640/ab-ba-is-a-nilpotent-matrix-if-it-commutes-with-a?rq=1