# If $AB+BA=0$ and $B=AX+XB$, then $B$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math

Suppose $A,B,X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and that $AB+BA=0$ and $B=AX+XA$. Prove that $B$ is a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem, what have you tried?

Comment: First I tried to show each eigenvalue is zero, with no success. Then I tried to show $B^n=0$ by multiplying the second equality by B and doing algebraic manipulation, still to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a related problem: [Show that a matrix is nilpotent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357566/show-that-a-matrix-is-nilpotent)

The proof for this one is almost the same.

We have $$AB=-BA$$, thus it follows by multiplying $B$ on the right, that 
$$AB^2 = -BAB = B^2 A$$
Then by induction, we have $$AB^n=(-1)^nB^nA.$$

Now, following the solution in the link: we have 
$$B^n = B^{n-1}B = B^{n-1}(AX+XA) = A (-1)^{n-1} B^{n-1}X + B^{n-1} XA.$$

Thus, $$\textrm{Tr} B^{2n} = 0 $$ for all $n$.

This shows that $B^2$ is nilpotent.