# Matrices such that $A^2+B^2=2AB$ have a nilpotent commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ non-commuting matrices with complex elements such that $A^2 + B^2 = 2AB$. Prove that there is at least one $m \leq \frac{n+1}{2}$ so that $(AB-BA)^m = O$, where $O$ is the null matrix.

Comment: Hint: try to show that $AB-BA=(A-B)^2$.

Comment: Please trying using MathJax formatting (it's the same syntax as LaTeX). It makes for a more readable text, attracting more attention.

Comment: I know that $AB-BA=(A-B)^2$, but how does it help me?($(A-B)^2 = A^2 - AB - BA + B^2, so  AB-BA=(A-B)^2$)

Comment: I propose a change in your title in order to attract attention and to stick to the real issue '"A difficult problem..." could be the title of at least half of the questions ... and is not informative at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, @Mosquite's comment is extremely helpful. The main idea is to use the argument in [Show that a matrix is nilpotent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357566/show-that-a-matrix-is-nilpotent) Let $C=AB-BA = (A-B)^2$ and we will prove that $\mathrm{tr}(C^k)=0$ for $k\geq 1$.

From $C=(A-B)^2$, we see that $C$ commutes with $A-B$. Thus, $C^k$ commutes with $A-B$ for any $k\geq 1$.

Since $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$, we have $\mathrm{tr}(C)=0$. Suppose that for some $k\geq 2$ we proved that $\mathrm{tr}(C^{k-1})=0$. Then by $\mathrm{tr} (XY)= \mathrm{tr} (YX)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(C^k)&= \mathrm{tr} C^{k-1}( AB-BA) \\
&= \mathrm{tr} C^{k-1}( (A-B)B+B^2-BA)\\
&=\mathrm{tr} ( (A-B) C^{k-1} B + C^{k-1}B(B-A) )\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(  C^{k-1}B(A-B) + C^{k-1}B(B-A)) =0.
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, the claim that $\mathrm{tr}(C^k)=0$ for $k\geq 1$ is proved. Consequently, $C$ is nilpotent so that $A-B$ is also nilpotent. Thus, $(A-B)^n=O$. Then for a least integer $m$ with $2m\geq n$, we have 
$$
(AB-BA)^m = (A-B)^{2m} = O.
$$
This $m$ satisfies $m\leq \frac{n+1}2$. So, we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!