# For all $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, if $[A, [A, B]] = 0$, then $[A, B]$ is nilpotent

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, nilpotence

$\newcommand{\tr}{\mathrm{Tr }}$
Let be $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ the set of complex-valued square matrices of order $n$ and $[A, B] = AB - BA$ a commutator.

If, for some $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, we have $[A, [A, B]] = 0$, then $[A, B]$ is nilpotent.

So: $[A, [A, B]] = 0$ says that $A$ and $[A, B]$ commutes.

Let be $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $X \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $[A, B]X = \lambda X$ (an eigenvalue/eigenvector pair), such values always exist as $[A, B] \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and must have $n$ eigenvalues.

Left-multiplication of the previous relation gives: $A[A, B]X = \lambda AX$.

By hypothesis, we have: $[A, B](AX) = \lambda (AX)$.

If we denote $E_{\lambda}$ the set of eigenvectors of $[A, B]$ for the $\lambda$ value, we have: $X \in E_{\lambda} \implies AX \in E_{\lambda}$.

As a result, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}, A^k X \in E_{\lambda}$.

Now, we also have $\tr [A, B] = 0$ because of properties on the trace.

If $A$ is not nilpotent or nilpotent for $k \geq n$, then: $(X, AX, \ldots, A^{n - 1} X)$ is linearly independent, as $\dim E_{\lambda} \leq n$ and $\dim E_{\lambda} \geq n$.

We conclude that $\dim E_{\lambda} = n$, finally: $n \lambda = 0$, now: $\lambda = 0$.

We conclude that $[A, B]$ is nilpotent.

If $A$ is nilpotent for $k \leq n - 1$, then $\dim E_{\lambda} \geq k$.

Here, I don't really know how to proceed, I'd like to show we cannot have any other value than $\lambda$ and it must be $0$ due to the trace.

Comment: This has been in MSE several times. Check $\mathrm{tr}[(AB-BA)^k]$.

Comment: @i707107 I tried to look at $[A, B]^k$ but due to $ABBA \neq BAAB$, I was not sure I could extract meaningful information from this. Except for the fact that I could look at it from an eigenvalue point of view, but in case of nilpotency of $A$, I don't see well how to use it…

Comment: See this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357566/show-that-a-matrix-is-nilpotent

Comment: @i707107 Thanks, more straightfoward than mine!