# Representing Matrix Of A Nilpotent Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I hope that this question isn't against the rules or anything.

I have the same question as this person, but I don't understand how to continue from his working and the answer he received:

[Linear independence in construction of Jordan canonical form basis for nilpotent endomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163202/linear-independence-in-construction-of-jordan-canonical-form-basis-for-nilpotent)

I think that he has constructed a certain basis for $V$ which contains bases for all the subspaces $U_i$, but I don't understand how to go on to prove the theorem he is trying to prove. I get that the first column of the representing matrix can be the zero vector, because the basis contains at least one vector from $U_{r-1}$.

I have given this thought, and I am not a strong maths student. Please be nice!